# “Let me say this on the outset …”

Tags: phrases, business-language

Is “let me say this on the outset” formal English in business-speak? What does it really mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Let me say this **at** the outset"

It's reasonable in a speech, but probably wouldn't be used in written English.
It means "let me make this clear at the start". Outset = setting out (as in a journey) = start.

Answer (score 2):

It's a strange phrasing; I would expect "Let me say this *at* the outset".  It's a bit bombastic and only really appropriate to spoken English, but it's certainly formal enough for business use, if that's what you're after.  It normally means that the speaker is calling attention to something that he or she believes should in some way be kept in mind as an important factor in whatever process is presently beginning.

Answer (score 1):

*Let me say this at the outset* is an odd construction. It is an informal way of expressing someone wishes to make a point clear before other points are made.

There are several alternatives that are equally colloquial and probably more common:

- *Let me make this clear.* (Assertive, possibly confrontational in some contexts.)
- *Let's address this now.* (Cooperative, objective.)
- *Allow me to be upfront about this.* (Candid, frank.)
- *I should mention now that...* (More informal, objective.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit like saying "Let me be frank."  It's not terribly formal, and it's also an expression that you wouldn't understand unless you had already been explained what it meant, which is in general bad when you're goal is to be clear in business talks.